# Remove over-current protection from 5 VDC common mobile/router charger

Tags: battery-charging, current-limiting, circuit-protection

When the negative and positive terminals are crossed the current stops then recovers again. I am trying to figure out what can be done to get full potential of the charger by removing this protection. I have seen people have removed this type of protection from PC power supplies to use them as battery chargers (Youtube). Please see attached images.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: First determine the controller IC, then get a data sheet. Use that data sheet to find out what feedback it uses to limit current, then remove or spoof that feedback. As a side note I do not feel like this will make a good battery charger.

Comment: I think it does not have a controller IC, I am trying to use them as parallel to increase current, but I need to remove this current protection.

Comment: Start tracing the circuit in the high voltage side,  that sot 23-6 probably does most of the work.

Comment: Do you mean this one?
![1][2]
https://i.imgur.com/mCvw8Vh.jpg

Comment: Yeah that one looks like it could get something done.

Comment: So, what should I do to bypass its protection?

Comment: I am trying to improve current using these charger modules in parellel but need to bypass its protection https://imgur.com/7Pj5pGE

Comment: You’ve shown us plenty of pictures of some random power supply but have not identified the actual part number of the controller ic. If you’re feeling brave, short circuit three resistors in parallel on the source of the mosfet. This will bypass the current limit. Note - it is likely the unit will go pop.

Comment: Sorry, on mosfet I am able to identify AAJF5 or AAJF8 not sure about the last digit, I did lookup AAJF it turns out to be a type of SOT 23-6, like bryan pointed out, but I am unable to find datasheet of AAJF Sot 23-6. I did found datasheet of SOT 23-6L, which I think is somewhat different from SOT 23-6.

Comment: How do you know that the design can cope with high current to begin with, and how do you know that you just won't burn your house down? The supply was **not** designed to be a constant current source. It **cannot** be operated as one unless you redesign it. And that's not something that just takes removal of a vital protection feature. **Do not** attempt what you're thinking of. It will not end well.

Answer (score 1):

AAJF is probably the SG6859AT

https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/sg6859a-d.pdf

[image: sg6859a application schem]

The description for the sense pin reads:

> Current sense. This pin senses the voltage across a resistor. When the voltage reaches the internal threshold, PWM output is disabled. This activates over-current protection. This pin also provides current amplitude information for current-mode control.

As such it requires current information to operate normally, and based on the performance reported by @techshqq removing this feedback is a bad idea.

—-

<strike>fAs @Kartman intuited, shorting those three resistors at the source pin of the FET (they combine to create the \$R_{CS}\$), or shorting SENSE to GND will disable the current limiting feature of this IC.</strike>

I'd like to reiterate that this supply is probably not going to make a great battery charger, especially with it's over-current safety removed.

Comment: Hi Bryan, thanks for answering. It didn't work, I shorted the SENSE with GND it went in flame, then on another module I put a jumper between GND and SENSE to be sure, again it went in flames, then I tried the @Kartman way and shorted the 3 resistors at the FET source pin, I think the thermistor failed this time, didnt work. 

Comment: @techshqq to be clear: when it flamed out was it under load, or was the output open circuit?

Comment: That resistor is also used for current mode PWM control, so with it shorted, the duty cycle will be extended to the point of inductor saturation and destruction. Try just using a lower value.

Comment: @Bryan the circuit was open, no load was attached when it happened.

Comment: @techshqq that makes sense, try following patechpaul’s advice and reducing that resistor value to get more current.

Comment: @Bryan Yes, I had already tried that one before, using a 10ohm resistor on the sense pin of the controller, it had improved the current rating but I am trying to use these kits in parallel to improve current when I use a couple of these kits in parallel to give me about 6 to 9 amps they start turning off and on one by one. This trick usually works on the other more simplified version of 5VDC modules but on this one due to current protection it's not.

Comment: You need an isolation diode on each power supply for parallel connection and current sharing.

Comment: @PStechPaul diodes might reduce voltage, still without anyway of disabling the protection, they are not working well in parallel. I had killed 5 modules in this attempt. I am wondering if there is a work around like replacing some components or controller ic?

Comment: Oversize Schottky diodes would only lose about 0.3 volts under load. Otherwise, your best (and maybe only) option is to build a proper charger circuit yourself. This power supply has probably been designed close to the limits of its components (transformer, especially), and trying to get much more than it was designed for will likely fail. Remember, that current sense resistor is NOT just for overcurrent protection.